# Why were my 'wrong language' flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I've been reviewing my flags in Flags raised section and found out that I keep getting rejected when flagging the question for the wrong language.

[image]
[image]

You can see from the image above that the questions are written in a wrong language, and that both of my flags got declined.

I flagged the questions by choosing the

> Flag > in need of moderator intervention > Writing the 'Wrong flag'
>   description

I wouldn't be complaining about it, but one month ago I got warned that some of my flags got declined. My only worry is not to be blocked from flagging.

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate for this: Non englisch posts should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking". These questions can be handled by the community itself without any moderator invention necessary. The declined message tells you that: Use standard flags instead of special moderator flags.

Comment: Reading from the flag descriptions, it's hard to tell this problem should be flagged as 'Unclear what you're asking'. Either way, the flag shouldn't get declined - maybe a warning not to use special moderator flags but definitely not a decline.

Comment: It's declined so one can learn how to properly use flags for their intended purpose. A warning is not nearly as clear ("It was approved, so I wasn't that wrong, right!?" sort of mentality). Anyway, just two declined flags over a long period of time aren't going to affect you negatively, simply learn and flag accordingly in the future.

Comment: FWIW I think most of us have gone through this part of the SO "learning curve". I sure remember this one! It takes time and effort to learn which flags/close vote reasons to use for which things. Good that you ask :-) And thanks for helping with site curation.

Comment: The declination of your flags was explained in the flag response: " declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging? "